# Run 2 loops in parallel with dependent values from 2 different methods of 2 classes

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-asyncio

I have 2 classes, the method of class1 has to iterate over a time step and calculate a time dependent value while the follow method of class2 has to register every 10 value of the history list of class1. How can I do this with asyncio so that both can run in parallel and the follow method of class2 is awiting every 10 value while the simulation method is running?

This is my attempt

```
class Class1:

    def __init__(self,time):
        self.time = time
        self.current_time = 0
        self.history = []

    def get_values(self):
        print('do something with time', self.current_time)
        self.current_time += 1

    async def run_simulation(self):
        while self.current_time  <= self.time:
            self.get_values()
            self.history.append(self.current_time)

class Class2:
    def __init__(self, class1 ,time_interval = 10):
        self.time_interval = time_interval
        self.class1 = class1


    async def measure(self):
        while self.class1.current_time <= self.class1.time:
            if self.class1.current_time%self.interval == 0:
                print(self.class1.current_time)

object1 = Class1(100)
object2 = Class2(object1,10)
asyncio.run(object1.run_simulation())
asyncio.run(object2.measure())
```

Do you have any ideas?

thank you

Comment: Due to the random nature of the training process, if you want to reproduce the exacts training results in both machines, you should provide a seed. Here you can read a more detailed explanation about it https://machinelearningmastery.com/reproducible-results-neural-networks-keras/

Comment: Do you mean `is one order of magnitude below than on PC2`?

Comment: Using the same pre-trained model is mandatory for your purpose, but you also need to ensure that in both machines, all the computations be in the exact same order. Due to all the random computations involved, you need to provide a `seed`

Comment: The only difference I see mentioned is that one requires a lower learning rate to converge. Could you mention other ways the results are different? Also, have you tried using the same version of tensorflow on both machines?

Comment: You can try using `tf.random.set_seed()` and `np.random.seed()` on both the system with same seed number and check if the result are different.

Comment: @LisLouise did you ever solve this? I am having the same issue with the same exact NN converging only on one PC but not the other, and I suspect it's a tensorflow issue